# How can Translate a website with a multilangue

Tags: symfony4

I need to translate my app with two languages, French and English

I have a locale in my route `/index/en` or `/index/fr`, but if I need to access my back office with a route `/index/login`
Symfony thinks login is a var _locale.

```
@Route(
    "/{_locale}", 
    name="index", 
    defaults={"_locale":"%locale%"}, 
    methods={"GET","POST"})
```

I tried to add a two another route but it's not working, I have the same problem.

Comment: Please go through the tutorial again. You are missing a route requirement.

Comment: thanks emix i resolve this when i had requirement. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [internationalized routing](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-internationalized-routing) introduced in `4.1`